# How can I correctly write the WHERE clause?

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file that is structured as follows:

```
<root>
   <State state="AZ" stateName="Arizona" stateKey="Arizona" >
      <menuVirtualPageName>Arizona.html</menuVirtualPageName>
      <Region regionKey="GreaterPhoenix" >
         <pageName>Phoenix.html</pageName>
      </Region>
   </State>
</root>
```

I have been trying to select a state, using a regionKey value.  Given that I already have a correct value for "thisState", I write the following Linq query

```
Dim stateQuery = (From dataStates In dataStatesXML...<Region> Where dataStatesXML...<State>.@stateKey = thisState Select New With {.virtualPageName = dataStates.<menuVirtualPageName>.Value.ToString(), .stateName = dataStates.@stateName.ToString()})
```

But I always get back an empty query result :(    Any ideas or suggestions much appreciated!!!

Comment: Did you get a chance to check my answer?

Comment: I got it to work using your answer.  Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
Dim state As String = (From x In xdoc.Descendants("Region") _
                    Where x.Attribute("regionKey").Value = "GreaterPhoenix" _
                    Select x.Parent.Attribute("state").Value).FirstOrDefault()
```

I am getting `AZ` as output.

**Edit:**

Just noticed you want to fetch `stateName` & `virtualPageName` as well, here is the query for that:-

```
Dim result = (From x In xdoc.Descendants("Region") _
   Where x.Attribute("regionKey").Value = "GreaterPhoenix"
   Select New With {.virtualPageName = x.Parent.Element("menuVirtualPageName").Value, _
                    .stateName = x.Parent.Attribute("stateName").Value}).ToList()
```